# How Artifactory manages Ivy descriptors

Tags: java, repository, ivy, artifactory

I'm trying to get Artifactory (OSS version) up-and-running for the first time and have successfully created a repo and deployed an artifact (joda-time-2.0) to it as a test.

But when it comes to the Ivy module descriptors (XML files), I'm a little confused:

- What should I name the XML files? The default artifact pattern I'm using is `[org]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[type]s/[module](-[classifier])-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).[ext]` which prompted Artifactory to store my joda JAR to `myRepo/joda-time/joda-time/2.0`; the module pattern is `[org]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[type]s/ivy-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).xml`, so should my descriptor be named `ivy-2.0.xml`?
- Shouldn't Artifactory have stored `joda-time-2.0.jar` under `myRepo/joda/joda-time/2.0/`? Since `joda` is the org, not `joda-time`? How do I change this?
- How do I upload the Ivy file into the repo? If I name the file `ivy-2.0.xml` then how will Artifactory know to place it in the JODA directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select various layout (inc. predefined ones) when configuring your repository in Arifactory. Read more about it [here](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts). I'd strongly recommend using Maven2 layout even when working with Ivy, it will allow build tools interoperability and using Artifactory more efficently, e.g. [GAVC search](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/GAVC+Search) works only for repositories with Maven2 layout. The m2 layout works perfect with Ivy.